# Riemannian metrics on a manifold with corners

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

For a smooth manifold with corners (although maybe there is no universally agreed definition of it), is there always a Riemannian metric making every face totally geodesic?

Is there any reference for such a result?

Comment: Take an atlas and a subordinate smooth partition of unity. The metric you get when pulling back the usual metric on open subsets of $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ along the charts of the atlas, and glueing them together with the partition of unity ought to work.

Comment: I think there is some condition for the partition of unities to guarantee the glued metric still makes the faces totally geodesic. Not all partitions of unity satisfy that.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat could you make answer from your comment, so the question will be removed from unanswered list?